# Where to modify product page in a woocommerce theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes

I would like to modify the look of the item picker for multiple items.
[image: the bottom right part] where can I find the file that holds this?

Comment: Is that a grouped product?You should review [template overrides](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/). That's likely the `single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php` template.

Comment: Modifying the the look? Use CSS. If you want to re-order you can also use CSS, tricky though, it's a table so direction rtl on the parent and direction ltr on the child would put them in the reverse order. You can also not repeat the template and see if the three filters on that page will work for you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can edit 
`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php` or
copy

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php
```

to

```
wp-content/themes/your-child-theme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php
```

and edit the copy template to suit. The copy template will override the plugin template and you can update WooCommerce without losing your custom template.

Comment: thanks!!  And now I cannot finde a file that sounds like it is holding the loop ... What I want to do is, that I want to also change the overview of the products, where all the products are sorted and listed by categroy, with the category name as title. any sugestions

Comment: @helle, I want to know if you changes the layout of content-single-product.php then what will happend when you update the WooCommerce plugin? will it overrite the my custom layout with WooCommerce layout after update?