# woocommerce product page - custom link which opens lightbox image

Tags: php, woocommerce

I really would like to have a custom link on the product page which opens a lightbox image. These images should be set somewhere on the product edit page.
I guess it is a bit of coding but should not be that difficult.
Example:
https://www.armedangels.de/frauenbekleidung-kleider-web-allover-avril-full-palm-10252599-220.html
Right under the Titel it says - "Was steckt drin" - I want something similar to this.
It would be great if someone could help me out with this problem.
Any held appreciated !!!
Thanks a lot and greetings from munich / Germany ...
Marc

Comment: Have you even tried? You should at least get something down for us to help you troubleshoot. We're not here to write all of your code for you.

Comment: What you need is a wordpress developer. Stackoverflow is for helping if you have problems with your coding - but not if need code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Difster, thx for the quick replie. I am not a coder but want to learn und understand it. I dont want the full coding done for me (well i would take it) but thats is not my intention. I was hoping that someone could probably give a a point where to start. And just a bit of information on what has to be done. Than I know what to look for and can give it a try ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one meta box to add custom link for every product from admin panel. 
You can reffere to this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336

After that you need to modify woocommerce's single-product.php file which you can do like this "activated-theme > woocommerce > single-product"

There will be some files in that folder or you can create it with the same name(plugins > woocommerce > templates > single-product) but you need to find out file where you want to display that custom link(may be title.php in your case if theme doesn't have modification)

For that you can refer to these links

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337693/5400174
- https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Well THX a lot for that information - now I know where to start ... Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Welcome, @Samurai089. I hope this answer is useful for you :)